# how to save bidirectional nested object in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

This is my invoice Entity

```
@OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "invoice", cascade = CascadeType.ALL )
@ToString.Exclude
private List< LineItem > lineItems;

@ManyToOne
@ToString.Exclude
@JoinColumn( name = "invoice_id", referencedColumnName = "id" )
private Invoice invoice;
```

Here i dont want to update all the fields in lineItem object which is  coming from the front end while iterating
i want set two new fields(setInvoice,setUUID) ... how it is possible

```
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    invoice.setId( uuid );
    invoice.setIsActive( 1 );
    invoice.setCreatedBy( "userId" );
    invoice.setLastUpdatedBy( "userId" );
    
    List< LineItem > lineItemsLists = new ArrayList<>();
    LineItem item = new LineItem();
    List< LineItem > lineItems = invoice.getLineItems();
    if(lineItems.size()>0){
        lineItems.forEach( lineItem -> {
            String lineItemUUID = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
          
            item.setId( lineItemUUID );
            item.setInvoice(  invoice );
            item.setDescription(  lineItem.getDescription() );
            lineItemsLists.add( item );
            
           
    
        } );
    }
     invoice.setLineItems( lineItemsLists );
  
    Invoice save = invoiceRepository.save( invoice );
```